# openshift template parameter expansion

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I'm trying to write a template for OpenShift 3.5. The problem that I'm running into is that Most of my parameters are usually the same value, but because they're not the same value often enough (probably 20% of the time), I need to allow the developer to specify the value of each parameter. The question here is this: Is there a way to do some kind of parameter expansion in OpenShift templates? Bash supports this syntax: `${VAR1:-"SomeDefaultValue"}`. That way, if `VAR1` isn't set, it has a default value that it can use. What I really want to do is this: `${OPTIONAL_VARIABLE:-${REQUIRED_VARIABLE}}`. That way, `OPTIONAL_VARIABLE` will be used if it's been set. Otherwise, it will use `REQUIRED_VARIABLE`, which the developer is forced to fill out. So, is there a way to do this or something similar in OpenShift templates?

Answer (score 1):

In the params for the template, specify a default `value` field:

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "APPLICATION_NAME",
        "displayName": "Application instance name",
        "description": "The name of the Wagtail instance",
        "value": "wagtail",
        "from": "[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}",
        "required": true
    },
```

If you need a random value generated as the default value, add `generate` and `from` fields. Use `expression` for the value of `generate` and then the value of the `from` field declares the format of the generated value.

```
    {
        "name": "DJANGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD",
        "displayName": "Application admin user password",
        "description": "Initial password for Wagtail admin user",
        "generate": "expression",
        "from": "[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}",
        "required": true
    },
```

See the following documentation.

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters